# Number of documents in a collection in MongoDB using RMongo

Tags: r, rmongo

How can I find the number of documents in a collection using the RMongo package?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `rmongodb` package which has more recent updates.

Connect to your base (here localhost) and use `mongo.count` to count documents in a specific collection.

```
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create() 
mongo.count(mongo = mongo, ns = coll_name)
```

With the argument `query` you also could count document resulting of a specific query if you want.